# KendoUI Autocomplete Issue

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, autocomplete, kendo-ui

I am trying to use the KendoUI autocomplete but it is giving me the error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Here is my javascript:

```
$("#toppersearch").kendoAutoComplete({
minLength: 1,
dataTextField: "name",
dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
       transport: {
           read: "Search/search/"+query,
       },
       schema: {
           data: "data"
       },
       serverFiltering: true,
       serverPaging: true,
       pageSize: 20
   }),
   placeholder: "Find a cake topper...",
   dataBound: function(e) {
    alert(e);
}
});
```

And my test return data:

```
require Ms.'SearchModel.php' ;
class Search extends Controller {

public $query ;
private $model ;

function __construct($query)
{
    parent::__construct() ;
    $this->model = new SearchModel ;
    $this->query = $query ;
    $this->search() ;
}

public function search()
{
    echo '{data:[{0:1,name:Horse}]}' ;
}

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is actually causing your error or not, but the JSON string you are returning is missing quotes around "Horse". It should be:

```
echo '{data:[{0:1,name:"Horse"}]}';
```